# Can I create a slide show with Balsamiq?

Tags: balsamiq

I'd like to simulate navigation and basic functionality using Balsamiq to simulate an iOS app.

I created a series of Balasmiq layouts and I'd like to connect these into an interactive slide show, wherein the individual buttons within each layout connects to a different screen.

Is this possible or do I have to use another tool like Flash?

Answer (score 2):

Balsamiq will allow you to link elements to each other. When you select an object the properties window has a "Link" dropdown and you can link to any other wireframe file in the same directory as the one you are working on. This then puts an arrow next to the control you are working with so that if you Alt+click that arrow you go to the linked form. If you export the entire directory as a PDF you will have a presentation that will work seamlessly with all links being functional.

Here is the tutorial for linking:

[Balsamiq linking tutorial](http://support.balsamiq.com/customer/portal/articles/1356143)